# Ad is not loading correctly (Server Error)

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, 500-server-error

Not sure where to put this, or if I should email the SO team, but since the ads are upvoted here....

Going to this page results in a server error:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

Comment: That's either an error, or it is an ad for a product I'd never buy.

Comment: @balpha: I think it's one of the open source ads -- The URL contains "OSS"

Comment: That's just a particularly clever ad.  If I could just figure out what it's trying to tell me...

Comment: Got that error also

Answer (score 2):

Yep, and these ad errors are in SO sidebar as well.

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-ad-gallery/37658#37658 :P

Answer (score 0):

I was going to report the same thing. The advertisement frame shows an ASP.NET YSOD.