# Ad server bug: "Server Error in '/' Application."

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ad is not loading correctly (Server Error)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37591/ad-is-not-loading-correctly-server-error)

Browsing SO, I found this interesting "ad"

http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/1649/23027303.png

Comment: Gotcha there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37591/ad-is-not-loading-correctly-server-error

Comment: Despite their track record, it isn't from woot!

Comment: @random: That would indeed be a good idea for them. I know that I noticed it more than others "ads". Anyway, seems like I've been visiting Meta not enough today.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-ad-gallery/37658#37658

Comment: Oh sure, rub in the no Fanatic badge. Anyway, two hours ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37648/bug-report-server-error-in-application - 10k

Comment: @random: I'm not only a non-Fanatic badge bearer, I'm a sub 5ker :( Seems like I'm not trying hard enough.

Comment: You might need to willfully not understand how the site actually works and then post feature-request after feature-request about how to change it for the better. You'll surely net some pity upvotes!